# Improve headtracking on Android using Google Cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I am building an application for use with Google Cardboard or something similar. I have some trouble with the headtracker though, as it's very jittery.

When I try demos from Fibrum for example, the headtracking is much more stable.

Is there a way to stabilize the headtracking, removing the jitteryness on Android? Does Fibrum and others use their own sensor fusion code, and is that why it's better?

My phone is a Motorola Moto G(2) 2014.

I am using the HeadTracker object directly in my code, using:

```
        headTracker.setNeckModelEnabled(true);
        headTracker.setGyroBiasEstimationEnabled(true);
        headTracker.getLastHeadView(headMatrix, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment on Reddit's GoogleCardboard sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/2jh7sw/very_shaky_google_cardboard_head_tracking/) implies that the Moto G's gyroscope is unstable. Have you looked at the output of the gyroscope when the phone is laying still on a table (do you get jitter) ?  Have you tried the HeadTracker on other manufacturer's phones ?

If you need to account for jittery sensors, you try to apply an RMS algorithm to minimize the jitter.

Comment: Yes, the phone has a jittery sensor indeed, most likely due to lacking a hardware gyroscope. However, I do wish to target this phone as well as other phones lacking a gyroscope. I will look into using an RMS algorithm, thanks.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://m.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/2syeb2/moto_2nd_gen_gyroscope_fix_request/), and it seems to work if the app used multiple sensor inputs to remove shaking, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hitlabnz.sensor_fusion_demo) does.